# Change from iOS Developer Program to Enterprise

Tags: ios-appstore, developer-program

I have enroled in iOS Developer Program. I'm creating a simple location app, but it is targeted for our company employes only. Now, I've figured out that I enroled in the wrong program, as it should have been Enterprise. I'm certain that my app will never pass in App Store review.

My question is if there's a migration path, where I could use my already paid $99 to change to the $299 Enterprise account. What will it take for me to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to just contact developer support and ask them if you can do this. My suspicion is that they would possibly credit you the difference or refund your individual account if it's a recent purchase.

- https://developer.apple.com/support/

Use the Contact Us link (currently) at the bottom of the page.

Comment: "I did contact them. Rigth on! They didn't migrate my account/Apple ID, but there was a refund since I didn't use the previous account for anything.